# IBM Business Process Manager Customizing Process Portal (V8.5.5) Upload/Edit fails

Tags: ibm-bpm

I am trying to customize the IBM Process portal login page (the logo).
I followed an article where they used a webDav tool to connect to the following folder: **/mum/contenthandler/mm/dav/filestore**

I am logged using the admin role,I installed the SSL cert and I edited the settings to ***Default to basic authentication when certificate authentication for the HTTPS client fails*** 
[image]
I still can't edit anything on the server's repository due to a bad request error.

Comment: WebDAV is returning with an error, do you have access to log files? It should return an error code, which would help with the debugging.

Comment: Hello thank you for the idea, I checked the cyberduck's logs and found the following error it is due the SSL cert 
2016-02-03 17:59:20,325 [Thread-0] ERROR ch.cyberduck.core.ssl.CustomTrustSSLProtocolSocketFactory - Failure NativePRNG SecureRandom not available obtaining secure random NativePRNG

Comment: After doing a quick search for that error, there seem to be recurring issues with Cyberduck: https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/8897 https://trac.cyberduck.io/ticket/9132 I would recommend trying another client.

Comment: I tried other Client webDav but the same problem persists (HTTP Bad request) even after many modifications with the security settings

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the Global Security setting on WAS console. Login to WAS console using admin credential. Go to

Security > Global security in the left panel. Open Web and SIP security and click on General settings on the right [refer attached screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdTuF.png)

After you click on General settings, below screen will appear. Make sure that the check box "Default to basic authentication when certificate authentication for the HTTPS client fails" is checked.
[refer image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxOIy.png)

Also when you are using WebDav, use admin credential having full access.